# OS X PATH problems: Home directory set to /Applications/XAMPP

Tags: php, bash, macos, xampp

I was using XAMPP, and added a XAMPP sub-directory to my PATH in ~/.bash_profile, and now for some reason all of a sudden /Applications/XAMPP is my home directory (e.g. when I type "cd ~" and do "ls", it only lists the contents of the XAMPP folder. And because of this, I can't find my ~/.bash_profile to revert the PATH back to normal. It seems to have disappeared. Any suggestions?

Comment: Running `PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO: ' bash -xlic ''` might give you insight to what is happening when you open your terminal.

Comment: @andlrc: Thank you! This helped me find where my bash_profile was located so I could change it, thus fixing the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not completely sure what causes you to end up in `/Applications/XAMPP`. But I can tell you a way to debug a login shell:

```
PS4='+ $BASH_SOURCE:$LINENO: ' bash -xlic ''
```

`-x` is for debug, `-l` is login, `-i` is interactive, and `-c ''` is a NOP command.

`PS4` will be appended on each line printed by `-x`, and in our case it will print file and line number from where the code is executed.